# Changing JSF data table cell background

Tags: jsf, colors, datatable, cell

How can I change the background of a jsf data table cell? I need to change the color of the whole cell, not the background of text in it.

EDIT:
The desired result is to have a table with:
`<td style="background-color: #ff9200">...</td>` where the actual background color is defined somewhere by the user and could be different for each `<td>`.

It's possible to do `<td><div style="background-color: ...">...</div></td>`, but that starts getting uglier.

Answer (score 1):

Just use CSS to give the `td` element of interest a `background` property with a color of interest.

```
td.someclass {
    background: pink;
}
```

You can specify CSS classes for `td` elements using `columnClasses` attribute of `<h:dataTable>`. Alternatively, if you want to apply this on all cells of the same row, rather use `rowClasses` attribute in combination with `tr.someclass td` CSS selector.

Comment: I would like to change specific cells (depending on its values). It seems to color all cells of a certain column, right?

Comment: Not if the value of `columnClasses` is dynamically served based on the current row. Alternatively you can also use CSS to remove all default paddings/spacings of the `table` and `td` and then just apply the background color on a parent block element which wraps the entire cell contents.